# MongoDB + merge dictionaries

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a database, which is constructed as

```
{"id":5,

 "type":{"hello":1,"sad":2,"luck":1}})
```

Now I do the search

```
 db.collection.distinct("type")
[
    {
        "hello" : 1,
        "sad" : 2
},
    {
        "hello" : 1,
        "sad" : 2,
        "luck" : 1
    }
]
```

Now I want to sum all the values for each key to a result like:

```
 { "hello" : 2, "sad" : 4, "luck" : 1 }}
```

Is  there a method to achieve this, thanks in advance.

Comment: You should change your structure to `{"id":5,"type":[{"k":"hello", "v":1},{"k":"luck", "v":1}, {"k":"sad", "v":2}]}` with key value pair. You can then use `db.collection.aggregate({"$unwind":"$type"}, {$group:{"_id":"$type.k", "count":{"$sum":"$type.v"}}})`

Comment: Thanks, sir, is it possible to make the search based on current data structure?

Answer (score 1):

Mongo 3.4.4 version

You can use `$objectToArray` which creates a array of key value pairs.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    "$project": {
        "type": {
            "$objectToArray": "$type"
        }
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": "$type"
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$type.k",
        "count": {
            "$sum": "$type.v"
        }
    }
})
```

Older Versions

You can use `mapreduce`

```
var map = function() {
   var type = this.type;
   Object.keys(type).forEach( function(key) { emit( key, type[key] ); } );
};

var reduce = function( key, values ) {
   return values.length;
};

db.collection.mapReduce( map, reduce, { out: { "inline" : 1}  } )['results']
```